# How to define CWinThread in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, pthreads

I have set an `int` variable for the `"EditBox"` control in **c++/mfc**. now I want to change its `value` in a `thread`.

I define a thread like the bellow :

```
CWinThread *pThread();

UINT FunctionThread(CthDlg& d)
{
    DWORD result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (i == 5000) i = 0;

        d.m_text1 = i;
        i++;
        d.UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
    return result;
}


void CthDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    pThread = AfxBeginThread(FunctionThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
}
```

Where's the Problem?

Comment: Did you debug the code? What is not working?

Comment: You should not update GUI from another thread. Only the main app thread is allowed to interact with GUI. So please use `PostMessage()` to notify the main thread that data has changed. The main thread should call `UpdateData()` in message handler.

Comment: In addition to @AndrewKomiagin's comment: You should put a call to the `Sleep` function statement inside your loop in the thread, because otherwise the updates will be incredibly fast and you probably won't see much.

Comment: @Mohammadreza "does not compile" : be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run your code in debug mode and under the debugger, then you would see that you get an assertion.

The problem is that MFC only allows access to a window from the thread that created the window. In your case that means that the main thread can access the windows, but the worker thread can not. `UpdateData` is accessing the windows, so this does not work in a worker thread.

So what you need to do is signal from the worker thread to the main thread that a new value is available and shall be displayed. For that signaling you can post a window message to the dialog window (`PostMessage`). Be sure not to use `SendMessage` because this will block until the message is received. You might run into a dead lock if the main thread is waiting for the worker thread and the worker thread is waiting for the main thread in `SendMessage`. When the main thread receives the message it can update the window control.

BTW, your code is not valid. `AfxBeginThread` requires a `AFX_THREADPROC` which is declared as `UINT __cdecl MyControllingFunction(LPVOID pParam);`. You need to change your thread function to

```
UINT __cdecl FunctionThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CthDlg& d = *reinterpret_cast<CthDlg*>(pParam);
```